# Ionic 6 Capacitor 3 Share Plugin Not Working with Android 12

Tags: android, capacitor, android-12, capacitor-plugin, ionic6

import { Share } from '@capacitor/share';

openSocial() {

```
Share.share({
  title: 'See cool stuff',
  text: 'Really awesome thing you need to see right meow',
  url: 'http://ionicframework.com/',
  dialogTitle: 'Share with buddies',
});
```

}

This code works fine till android 11. But app crashes with android 12 targetsdk=32.

Do I need to make any changes in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Have you managed to solve it please ? @Prashant

Answer (score 1):

If you are using capacitor 3 don’t target SDK 32, stick with SDK until capacitor 4 is released with official support and all those SDK 32 crashes fixed.

Targeting SDK 32 is not going to be mandatory until August for new apps and November for existing apps. Capacitor 4 will be launched before that.

Comment: If I don't target SDK 32 then my app is not running on Android 12 Devices. It is crashing.

Comment: What’s the crash message? For me it’s working fine on android 12 devices while targeting SDK 30, targeting SDK 32 is what makes them crash